# How to get the diagnostics message from the number with Intel C Compiler

Tags: c, gcc, icc

I have a project which is compiled with Intel C Compiler v15 and uses `Makefile` to do that. My target is to compile this project with `gcc`.
While doing that i observed in `Makefile`, `-we277 -we147 -we 117` flags are passed to the compiler.
The `-we` flag raises that particular diagnostic message as error.

Now I want to include similar flag to `gcc` compiler. however, I could not find any reference to the warning message or any info related to the warning `117/277/147`.

Is there any official documentation to get such info?
I know MSVC provided warning code along with diagnostic message in the official website but is there any similar thing to ICC compiler as well?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: You could remove these options from the makefile and see what messages are created and then check for corresponding GCC option.

Comment: @Gerhardh, I thought of doing that.

But in the halfway it reminded me that since the code is already compiled with icc compiler those errors might have been fixed in the code. So removing the flags might not raise that particular error again with the same code.

Comment: I know close to nothing about ICC but [the manual](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/error-handling-1/warnings-errors-and-remarks.html) describes an option that you should be able to use to get info on the codes: "*diag-dump:
Tells the compiler to print all enabled diagnostic messages and stop compilation.*

Comment: If the issues have been fixed you might just remove these options. *If it ain't broken, don't fix it.*

Comment: @kaylum,  _diag-dump_ gives information about all the enabled diagnostic messages. This flag has given most of the diagnostics i'm looking for. Thanks!!